# Is it dangerous to share my dmesg file?

Tags: linux, privacy, dmesg

I'm developing a project where I have to imitate Linux startup sequence. What I thought about, was of course, putting my `dmesg` into it. Is it dangerous? Will I share any sensitive information?

This will be publicly available on a website, as an intro. The system is Linux Mint, I'm concerned because I'm not sure if some sensitive data (ex. passwords, my IP address) appears in the `dmesg`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its highly unlikely to have passwords or IP addresses, but it would most likely have information sufficient to give a sufficiently motivated attacker insights into your hardware, software and possibly disk layout.  This information could be used to customise an attack.

(For example, if they know the kind of CPU and kernel, they may be able to better craft a branch prediction attack - but it would still require access to the system first)

A better way to do this might be to launch Linux in virtualised hardware and put the dmesg contents of that.